# Tensorflow: is this normal behaviour of Batch normalization?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

See the screenshot. Without batch normalization is the blue line. Accuracy in the upper plot, loss in the lower one. So without BN the loss decreases slowly and the accuracy increases slowly, expected behaviour.

But then I try batch normalization. Training loss converges quite fast to values near zero. So much better than without, but testing accuracy on both train and test sets give worse results.
[image]

I based my implementation on this: http://ruishu.io/2016/12/27/batchnorm/
So adding batch norm to a layer like this:

```
h1_p_bn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(h1_p, center=True, scale=True, is_training=self.is_training,scope='bn1')
```

with model.is_training a placeholder that is set to zero when testing accuracy (upper plot).

I do this as well:

```
# Requirement from tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    # Ensures that we execute the update_ops before performing the train_step
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
    self.train_op = optimizer.minimize(self.loss, global_step=global_step)
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Do you change self.is_training to False while testing because batch normalization maintains a global mean and variance in case of testing but  running one during training. Also, make sure your batch size isn't too small, also see if passing as big a batch during testing as you passed during training works.

Comment: Yes, I do change self.is_training. Can there be something wrong with scope? Does it matter what I fill in there?

Comment: Because now for every layer I fill in a different scope bn1, bn2, etc. Otherwise I get ValueError: Variable bn/beta already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

Comment: You need to include more code from your model.  if your training loss is 0 then your training accuracy should be near 100%.  You can ignore the test results and the UPDATE_OPS for now as those don't impact your training accuracy.

Comment: I think that is because loss is computed on 256 random picked examples from the training set and accuracy is measured on the full training and test set. But good point, I'll do the accuracy on 256 random samples too and see what the result is then.

Comment: @user728291 "When examples in a minibatch are not sampled independently, batchnorm can perform rather poorly." This is the reason, training accuracy was not near 100%. When sampling independently training accuracy is near 100%. But the issue with training and inference stays. This very recent paper, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.03275.pdf, shows a similar plot as I show here, maybe Batch Renormalization is the solution

Comment: Hello, I have observed similar thing in my data, without batch norm my training gets stuck at 80% accuracy, but gives better generalization result on test data. Using batch norm I can get the training accuracy up to 85 % or so but the performance on test data gets really bad. I using VGG 16 network, my own keras implementation . I have no explanation for this. Does any one know whats going on?